# What does "the support of $f$ lies in $V$ mean?"

Tags: general-topology

I have come across similar phrases and I am not sure what they mean. For example, if the phrase states "the support of $f(x)$ lies in a set $V$, does it mean that $V$ contains all $x$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$, or does it mean that for some subset of $A$ of $V$, $f(A)\neq 0$?

Comment: It means the first.

Comment: The second is rather trivial. It holds for any set containing any point which maps not to zero under $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the first. The support of a function $f$ is the collection of points in the domain that do not map to $0$.

To say the support lies in $V$, we mean the support is a subset of $V$. Now if the function you choose is the $0$ function, there is never a non-empty $A$ so that $f(A)\neq 0$ (I assume, you implicitly mean, $\forall a \in A (f(a)\neq 0)$.

Furthermore, if there is some $A\subseteq V$ which satisfies $f(A)\neq 0$ it does not mean the support is $A$, or that it lies in $V$, as you haven't also declared that no points which aren't in $A$, don't evaluate to something non-zero.

Comment: Actually my professor defines support as the closure of set where $f$ has nonzero image.

Comment: @JohnZHANG Ah, well your notion is more topological. "Support" gets used in lots of different places, e.g. the direct sum vs direct product of infinitely many groups. So there may be slight perturbations in the definition from place to place. If the OPs definition requires the closure, then they just use the closure.